# passing lambda as an argument in this example

Tags: scheme

The following procedure random-choice contains a procedure called choice:

```
(define (random-choice strategy-1 strategy-2) 
 (choice strategy-1
 strategy-2
 (lambda (ship-state) (= (random 2) 0))))
```

How do I create the procedure choice that chooses the two strategies at random?
Also can you explain how lambda can be passed as an argument from procedure to procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you would choose a value at random, between two possible values:

```
(define (choice s1 s2)
  (if (zero? (random 2)) s1 s2))
```

The procedure returns the randomly chosen value, it's up to you how to use it. And a `lambda` can be passed as an argument as any other value, there isn't anything different about it. For example:

```
((choice (lambda (x) (first x))
         (lambda (x) (last  x)))
 '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

The above will select randomly between a strategy for picking either the first or the last element in a list, and then it applies the selection to a list. Run it several times, you'll see that sometimes `1` is returned, and sometimes `5` is returned.

Comment: The `lambda`s in the second part are for illustration purposes only, in practice the same function call could have been written more concisely like this: `((choice first last) '(1 2 3 4 5))`